# spring security pass thru URL

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot 1.1.7 app using spring-security and spring-mvc.  I have a login form for most users to login and access the site just fine.  However, I have a new requirement that they want to submit a url request and get XML results back.   I tried adding a security configuration that would allow the url to be bypassed, but my response is always the HTML for my login page.

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller(value = "/remote")
public class RemoteSearchController {

    @Autowired
    private SearchService searchService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
     public List<Sdn> searchTreasury(@ModelAttribute SdnSearch sdnSearch, @PathVariable String username, @PathVariable String password, @PathVariable String sdnName, Authentication authentication) {

     // do some work and return a list of objects into XML
     ...
     }
  }
```

Here is my Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

     http
         .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers( "/remote/search").permitAll().anyRequest();
    }

// adding this method results in a 404 - otherwise a login html is returned.
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/remote/search**",
                        "/remote/search/**" );

        return;
    }
```

And then using a REST client I submit this:

```
http://localhost:9001/remote/search?username=user&password=password&sdnName=Victoria
```

I thought perhaps the username and password would get picked up for authentication.  But apparently this method never gets hit.  And, overriding the configure(WebSecurity web) results in a 404.

UPDATE:
Per Dave S, I changed my Controller to be a Controller and not a bean:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remote/search{username}{password}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public List<Sdn> search(@ModelAttribute SdnSearch sdnSearch, @PathVariable String username, @PathVariable String password,  Authentication authentication) {
 List<Sdn> foundSdns = sdnSearchService.find( sdnSearch );
        auditService.logSearchResults( authentication.getName() );
        return foundSdns;
}
```

Coupled with my Security Config, this allows unauthenticated searches but  The username, password, and Authentication parameters are null so I can't manually authenticate.

If this is going to be truly REST, it would seem that I need to submit two requests, one for a token, the other to search with that token in the header.   But I am not sure how to set that up in a way that a customer can do that easily with URL requests.

Comment: Do you want the search queries to be authenticated or not (your configuration suggests not, but then you waft a username and password at it)?

Comment: The 404 suggests that your `@RequestMapping` is not being registered (you should see it in logs on startup). Is the `@Controller` actually a `@Bean`?

Comment: I think the search should be authenticated, and I thought if I passed in the username/password then I could use those to manually authenticate.  However, I don't think sending those in as parameters would be very secure so I need to rethink this approach.

Comment: Indeed. If I were you I would just rely on the client (e.g. browser) to send a cookie. Then you can authenticate as normal.

Comment: So would that require them to make two calls?  Not sure how this would work if so.  Do you know of any examples that I can review?

Comment: I guess it's 1+N (1 request to login and N subsequent authenticated requests). Users are fairly well conditioned to click on a login link, or follow instructions from a login page, so the first request is easy for them to understand. I'm working on some samples for some blogs, so watch out in http://blog.spring.io. There are plenty of Spring Security samples in the internet though (it's nothing special).